# Using Selenium to interact with a webpage but javascript doesn't execute for date selection

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have this snip of an HTML from a webpage. It is a dropdown box which selects to and from date for articles. (The current values/ default values are 1992-03-06 to Today)

```
<div class="search-select__dates" y-name="range" style="">
   <div class="mb-2">
      <label class="search-select__dates__label">From&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="hidden" value="1992-03-06" class="search-select__dates__date form-control flatpickr-input" y-name="from"><input class="input-flatpickr" placeholder="" tabindex="0" type="text" readonly="readonly">
   </div>
   <div class="">
      <label class="search-select__dates__label">To&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="hidden" value="2023-04-27" class="search-select__dates__date form-control flatpickr-input" y-name="to"><input class="input-flatpickr" placeholder="" tabindex="0" type="text" readonly="readonly">
   </div>
</div>
```

I am using Selenium to interact with the page and possibly change the date so that I can scrape the content on the website.

This is how my current code looks

```
# find the input element
from_date = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-select__dates input[y-name='from']")
to_date = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-select__dates input[y-name='to']")

# execute JavaScript to set the value of the input element
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '2023-04-20'", from_date)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '2023-04-20'", to_date)
```

This is part of a search tab. I can change everything else in the search tab other than the date. I have tried By.XPATH, By.CLASS_NAME, By.CSS_SELECTOR. Also thought that it might be a problem with the javascript enabler so I included `options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")` before I opened the Chromedriver to get the URL. The same stuff works with other portions of the search bar (send the search term, press the search button, select the category of articles required etc. just the date is not working). Is there something I am missing?